# Nginx block malicious requests per app vs entire server

Tags: nginx

Assuming a VPS with multiple applications, a common probe of malicious actors is to request known paths, such as

```
/wp-content/
/solr/
```

The goal is to simply deny any response to such requests and not even forward the request to the application.

```
location ~ \./wp-content/\. {
    deny all;
}
location ~ \./solr/\. {
    deny all;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

The above syntax attempts to deny any request where the string `/wp-content/` or `/solr/` is invoked, while returning the same for all php requests.  With a single site, this could be included in the `/site-enabled/default` file, or replicated in each application defined in that directory according to its stack.

But in a  multi-application context where the applications have similar stacks, how can this be refactored for the overall server  (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is not meant for this, IMHO) ?

Comment: Your `\./wp-content/\.`, `\./solr/\.` regexes match `./wp-content/.`, `./solr/.` strings, not the `/wp-content/`, `/solr/` ones. To deny those paths you can use `location ~ /(wp-content|solr)/ { ... }` for example. And these locations should be replicated in each `server` block, I don't see any other way to do it. The only thing, you can define all those locations in a some file and then use an `include` directive for all the `server` blocks.

Comment: OK.  I crossed my wires considering the `dot` as a regex 'any character'  wild card.  Helpful.

Comment: It is really an 'any character' wildcard until it is prepended with slash, but when it is, it is just a dot. And any of `/wp-content/`, `prefix/wp-content/`, `/wp-content/suffix`, `prefix/wp-content/suffix` strings will match a `/wp-content/` regex, so unless you really want to match only strings with some prefix and suffix, you shouldn't add that dot to your regex.